# SelectNextControl is selecting itself

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, keydown

### The problem

I'm trying to get a text field to process `Tab` and `Escape` to handle a user password field. I currently have an event firing on `PreviewKeyDown` to allow me to catch `Escape` and `Tab` on the KeyDown event and then a `KeyDown` event to process it as follows:

```
private void passwordText_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
   {
      bool success = this.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, false, true, true);
      e.Handled = true;
      e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
   }
   else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
   {
      keepPassword = false;
      bool success = this.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, false, true, true);
      e.Handled = true;
      e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
   }
   else
   {
      e.Handled = false;
      base.OnKeyDown(e);
   }
}

private void passwordText_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab || e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
   {
      e.IsInputKey = true;
   }
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that the `SelectNextControl` command returns true, but the `ActiveControl` does not change. It's still on the `passwordText` control.

### Further Insight

It's calling the `Leave` override, and then the `Enter` override. If I remove `Leave` from the events, it correctly selects the next control. I'm posting the code from `Leave` here while I puzzle things through:

```
  private void passwordText_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (passwordText.ReadOnly == false)
     {
        if (keepPassword) // This is used to handle the case of using ESC to cancel the password entry.
        {
           // Change user password accordingly.
           password = GlobalDataStore.HashPassword(passwordText.Text);
        }
        else
        {
           keepPassword = true;
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(passwordText.Text))
        {
           passwordText.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
           passwordText.Text = "(Hashed Password)";
        }
        passwordText.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;

        passwordText.ReadOnly = true;
     }
  }
```

### Current Workaround

I moved the guts of the `Leave` Event into a separate function, `ProcessPasswordTextLeave()`. Inside the `KeyDown` event, before I do the select, I remove the `Leave` Event, do the Select, run the `ProcessPasswordTextLeave()` function, then add the `Leave` Event again. Messy, but it works for now. I would prefer something more elegant. I'd also like to know why processing it as a `Leave` event restore focus to it.

Comment: Why are you calling *passwordText_PreviewKeyDown*? In *passwordText_KeyDown* why are you using `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`, `base.OnKeyDown(e);` and `e.Handled = false;`? I have tested the code and works fine.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε:
Without PreviewKeyDown, the Escape and Tab keys don't fire KeyDown events, possibly because the form is intercepting them. As regarding using the event properties, I had thought that was the proper way of indicating that the key had been properly processed.

Comment: You don't need *passwordText_PreviewKeyDown* and all that i mentioned. You don't even need to check for the *tab*. It automatically goes to next control, if there is one.

Comment: Hmm... I'm starting to suspect that it may be a property of this ValidatingTextBox used by my company, so this may be an idiosyncratic thing. If I learn more, I will post as much.